# Add CPT as subpage under custom page

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

I have created a menu page with the following code:

```
add_menu_page('My Page', 'My Page', 'administrator', 'admin.php?page=my_page', array($this, 'my_page'));
```

And now I want to use custom post types on this page, also I want to create a few other custom post types, that are displayed as subpages from this page.

I can't really find how to do this, anyone who can give me some suggestions?

---

Edit: What I want to achieve is the following:

A menu group with the following pages:

Tournaments
 - Tournaments
 - Matches
 - Players
 - ...

All of the subpages are custom post types. I need a neat way to achieve this.

Comment: What happened when you used `add_submenu_page()` with the same trick?

Comment: What do you exactly mean? Can you provide examples?

Comment: Sorry! I misunderstood your question. Why do you need to create a menu page first then to assign a post type there? A post type creation will automatically provide you that, isn't that? Can you please [edit] your question, clarify your mission?

Comment: You should be able to provide the parent page slug to the `show_in_menu` value when you register your CPT.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to provide the slug of your top level page (`admin.php?page=my_page`) when registering your CPT(s):

```
register_post_type( 'matches',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Matches' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Match' )
         ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    // Add your page slug to 'show_in_menu'
    'show_in_menu' => 'admin.php?page=my_page'
    )
);
```